# How do I capture words that are different from specific word using RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, backreference, regex-lookarounds

I wanted to know, how do I capture any word which is not exactly "***yellow***". e.g.: "*red*".

I have tried the following regex:

```
(?!(yellow))
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3mgEsBz667vBweEh)

... but I have two problems:

1. It does not capture (creates a backreference) for matching expression (e.g.: "*red*")
2. "*yellowwwwww*" does not match my regex, even though it is different from "***yellow***".

Can you help me correcting my regex?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your string? Just a word, or many separated by spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture any word which is NOT `yellow` you can use:

```
\b((?!\byellow\b)\w+)\b
```

#### Online Demo: https://www.debuggex.com/r/S-qTilRd3WJqUP6x

Comment: This won't match `yellowwww`, whereas the OP wants to do so :/ You should probably use sthg like `\b((?!yellow\b)\w+)\b`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(?!yellow$)
```

The inner parenthesis in your original regex are needed only if you want to capture the group

The `$` ensures that only `yellow` will not match. If you want to use it inside a phrase use this instead

```
(?!yellow\b)
```